# Can Apache be configured to serve only world-readable files?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I'm running an experimental just-for-fun Apache web server. Part of the idea behind this server is that it should be unusually open to the public; for example, the root filesystem should be open for anyone to browse. (Indeed, here it is: http://sylvester.s.zbasu.net/rootfs/) As a consequence, security is going to take a back seat.

That said, there are things which Apache should be able to access, but the public should not. The example which I'm running into is a Django site. The file `settings.py` must be readable by Apache, or else Django won't work. But `settings.py` must not be readable by the public, since it contains a secret key. So the file should be owned by `www-data`, but Apache should nevertheless refuse to serve it.

One possible solution (thanks to `ellipsis753` on Freenode) is to create a special directive, perhaps in an `.htaccess` file, telling Apache not to serve this file. However, I figure that if a file isn't readable by all users, it probably shouldn't be served by Apache, either.

Can I tell Apache that if a file isn't world-readable, then it shouldn't be served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your Django application under FastCGI or in mod_wsgi's Daemon mode, then you can run it as a different user than the one Apache is running under.  Then, you can completely remove Apache's and World's permission to read any file that you do not want to serve.

For example, note that your password file [`/etc/shadow`](http://sylvester.s.zbasu.net/rootfs/etc/shadow) is already not accessible because Apache does not have permissions on it and it is not world-readable.  If you create a new user, say `web-apps` for example, and add `WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=web-apps ...` to the Apache configuration, then you can have the Django application be owned by the `web-apps` user, with its configuration file not world-readable, like the `shadow` file already is.

Comment: Yup, that works. Of course, I needed to add a `WSGIProcessGroup` directive as well. For some reason, I also had to edit my `wsgi.py` to append the project directory to `sys.path`, as described in this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4750766/1108505 I don't know why this was necessary when using `WSGIDaemonProcess` but not necessary otherwise.